# Spellcheck attribute inside webbrowser wpf C# contextmenu position change

Tags: c#, wpf, dom, contextmenu, spell-checking

I have a wpf webbrowser control inside a windows popup and need to edit the html elements inside it. I used following code for setting it's attributes and I want the spell check to work inside the webbrowser.

```
doc = webBrowser.Document as HTMLDocument;
doc.designMode = "On";
WebEditorBehavior.SetHtml(Gui.webEditorGlobal, Gui.getHTML());
if (doc != null && doc.body != null)
{
    doc.body.setAttribute("width", Width.ToString() + "px");
    doc.body.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    doc.body.setAttribute("spellcheck", "true");
    //doc.body.setAttribute("s");
}
```

Now when I see the error in spell, on right click the internet explorer menu works but the position is not relative to the WebBrowser, it is relative to the whole screen. 
But the simple right click is relative to the mouse position and works fine. This is a weird behavior. Any ideas or help would be appreciated.
Cheers!
Screen shot is below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTrmn.png)

Answer (score -1):

I was having this same issue, and looking into it further it looks like this is an issue with Windows 10 and Internet Explorer, not the WebBrowser control itself (see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-spell-check-menu-position/2767cd63-38fc-48aa-a834-e30b9cc53b3c)).

I tried opening outlook in IE11 and got the same behaviour.

Comment: Since it does not provide a solution, it`s more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add comments yet so this is the best I can do for now.

Comment: Wich means you have to wait :-)  We all got through it, don't worry.